# Library to embed 3D view in a swing app?

Tags: java, swing, 3d

I'm currently searching for a 3d library that I could embed in a Swing application. This library doesn't necessarily have to be a huge thing as I mainly intend to give a 3D representation of some shapes, and certainly rotate around them.

My main concern is to get something as easy to set up and to deploy as possible. 
Do you have any clue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just embed Java3D in your application.

http://java3d.j3d.org/tutorials/quick_fix/swing.html

You can also embed Jogl (Java OpenGL) with Swing.

http://cld.blog-city.com/mixing_java_2d_and_3d_jogl_in_a_swing_application.htm

Java3D would be higher level so it may be a better choice.